# Rails 3 - Select objects which do not include associated model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

(Using Rails 3)

I have 2 models (Vehicle and Capabilities) in a has_many through association.

So Vehicle 1 can have Capability 1 (eg towing), Capability 2 (eg passenger), Capability 3 (eg flying), etc.

```
v = Vehicle.first
v.capabilities.pluck(:name) #=> will give something like ['towing', 'passenger', 'flying']
```

I want to find all vehicles which must not have a particular capability, eg all vehicles which cannot fly.

I have tried queries similar to this below but it still includes flying vehicles, I think mainly because the airplane also has other capabilities.

```
non_flying = Vehicle.includes(:capabilities).where('capabilities.id NOT IN (?)', [2,3])
non_flying.first.capabilities.pluck(:name) #=> will give something like ['towing'].
```

Note that the flying capability is not included, but I just do not want this vehicle returned at all. How would I write this?

If possible, I would rather not use meta_wheel or squeel gems, but any arel_table implementation is welcome unless there is a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing something similar to this, inspired by Thaha kp's answer.

```
# Get all flying vehicles first
subquery = Vehicle.joins(:capabilities).where("capabilities.id IN (?)", 3).pluck("vehicles.id") 

# Then get all vehicles not in this flying vehicles array
non_flying = Vehicle.where('vehicles.id NOT IN (?)', subquery).all
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
non_flying = Vehicle.all - Vehicle.includes(:capabilities).where('capabilities.id IN (?)', [2,3]).all
```